# Batch exits with an error because of space in IF condition on comparing a string with an ENV

Tags: batch-file, cmd, space

I'm trying to make a table of possible inputs for the end user, but one of the inputs is causing the program to crash as there is a space. I know that usually enclosing the input with " " is the correct thing to do, but it does not work in this case, here is the code:

```
SET /P ANSWER=%ANSWER%
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={help} (goto :FunctionList)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={?} (goto :FunctionList)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={clear} (goto :clear)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={tutorial} (goto :tutorial)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={New User} (goto :NewUser) **--Offending line**
```

The line :

```
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={New User} (goto :NewUser)
```

refuses to go to the the following part, regardless of the `{New User}` being inclosed by " " or not.

```
:NewUser
    SET /P USERNAME=Please enter your desired username:
    SET /P PASSWORD=Please enter your desired password:
```

Comment: Use `"` double quotes instead of `{` and `}` as follows: `if /i "%ANSWER%"=="help" (goto :FunctionList)` etc.

Comment: When I read the title of this topic, I thought: "No way, Batch environment is 64 MB size!" **`8/`** Try to post clearer titles in your questions. I encourage you change this one to: "IF command fail because of space in a variable".

Comment: Cross posted to [su] [Batch file error because of space in input string](http://superuser.com/q/958047). Please don't do this. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pair of double-quotes instead of braces:

```
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="New User" (goto :NewUser)
```

The command line interpreter treats double-quoted arguments like `"New User"` as a single one because the double-quotes are handled especially.  However, braces do not have a special meaning, so the command interpreter sees two arguments `{New` and `User}` in your case, but only one is expected after the `==`.